# Getter Setter Method - Taking variable from .sol into .js

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript

new to coding here. I'm trying to call this seed variable from my contract into my .js file and from googling the get & set method is the easiest.

This is what I had in my contract

```
uint256 seed; //empty seed. can be change when wave fx is called.

function getSeedValue() public view returns (uint256) {
    return seed;
}

function setSeedValue(uint256 _seed) public {
    seed = _seed; 
    }
```

This is what I'm running to get the seed number in my .js file.

```
try{
  const setSeedNumber = await waveContract.setSeedValue;
  var seedNumber = await waveContract.getSeedValue(setSeedNumber);
  console.log(seedNumber);
}
catch(error){
  console.log("THIS SHIT DOESNT WORK");
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: it is showing as undefined in terminal when I called for seedNumber